Family comedy movie about a New York taxi laden with gadgets
There might be some false-memory syndrome going on so there could be mistakes with some specifics:

Movie about a yellow New York taxi cab.


It wasn't a modern taxi design, I'd say the vehicle itself was probably from the 1960s (like this design or this)
I don't know/remember if the movie was definitely set in New York, I think the driver was Italian-American, which is stereotypically associated with New York.

I think the movie was made in the 1970s or 1980s. It was in color.
The taxi vehicle had a number of "gadgets"


There was a scene where (I think) the taxi ran out of gas, so the driver got out and put a giant clockwork key in the back and turned it, and the taxi ran on clockwork power.
Another scene had the taxi enter a narrow alley and the wheels popped out and rotated to contact the walls, then it "climbed up" the alley vertically. I recall the driver was a woman, not the taxi's usual driver, and I think she was using the taxi to investigate a crime or something.


That's all I remember, unfortunately - I saw it on TV in the UK in the early-1990s. So it could have been a TV show too, I suppose.
Searching online for terms like "clockwork taxi" or "alley climb taxi" doesn't return anything relevant, unfortunately.

Since you're bringing up false-memory syndrome I'll suggest Scrooged (1988) because the 'gadgetty' taxi fits the description. Does this scene ring any bells? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0zvX6AGd7Q

@Dannie No, that's definitely not it, sorry.

All the scenes seem to come from a german movie called Ein Käfer auf Extratour featuring a yellow Beetle named "Dudu". I could not find the english title of that movies. They where the response to the Disney "Herbie"- movies that also feature a Beetle driving and winning car- races. 
The beetle "Dudu" belongs to a guy called "Jimmy Bondy" and has a lot of features. In addition Dudu is kind of intelligent and can make his own decisions. 
On this link you can find images of the described scenes, they are from the named movie Ein Käfer auf Extratour:  


In that scene Dudu is driven by Jimmy Bondy, but the wheel- thing is used often in the different movies, so the woman driver you remember might be from another scene.
There were 5 movies between 1971 and 1978 as stated in this (german) Wiki- article
